# PHP facade pattern object reuse

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, reusability, facade

for performance reasons, im trying to reuse facade object which is passed to provided handler,
there is a simplified demonstration of what im trying to achieve:

```php
class A
{
  public $b,$f;
  function __construct($f)
  {
    $this->b = new B($this);
    $this->f = $f;
  }
  function invoke()
  {
    ($this->f)(new B($this, 1)); # this works
    ($this->f)($this->b->set(1)); # this fails
  }
}
class B
{
  function __construct(
    private $a,
    private $i=0
  ) {}
  protected function set(int $i): self
  {
    $this->i = $i;
    return $this;
  }
  function get() {
    return $this->i;
  }
}
$a = new A(function(object $b) {
  $b->get();# OK
  $b->set(2);# FAIL, kind of protected
});
$a->invoke();
```

i tried inheriting both classes from an empty abstract object, but without luck.

im expecting that there is some language feature that makes friendly objects or approach im unaware of.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do exactly, but `B::set()` is protected, so you can't call it from the outside.

Comment: Since `set()` is protected, you can only call it from methods of `B` or its super/subclasses. You're trying to call `$b->set(2)` from a regular function.

Comment: I don't understand what the title has to do with the problem. The problem is a simple one of access / visibility, not related to facades or reuse.

Comment: im trying to protect properties and a method from usage in handler (anonymous function or outside function). how to do that without re-creating B object? i know that it is protected guys, see, i wrote a comment there, that it is protected. but still i wish to reuse that object without re-creation, by resetting some props

Comment: php doesn't have a concept of friend class (although it was proposed), you have 3 options: 1) make `set` method public 2) make `set` method public and inspect backtrace to ensure that the `set` method was called from allowed caller - the `A` class 3) bypass accessibility through reflections

Comment: worth mentioning that both 2) and 3) are somewhat wrong and you should avoid these. you enforced the kind of usage of your class by making that `$i` property private and `set` method protected, so its actually design problem. would make much more sense if you had all properties public for B class and making `$b` property in A class private, that way the B class properties/methods are actually protected as long as you keep the object inside A class which guard it